# How do I get queries and query count for a page?

Tags: 8, performance

In Drupal 7 the query log of the Devel module contained a table which had a query log with a much better overview than what Webprofiler is offering for Drupal 8.

In Drupal 8 there's no aggregation or sorting possible. (How many of the same queries are there? How much time are they taking? Which is the heaviest query to address?)

> [image: Devel Drupal 7 querylog]

> [image: Webprofiler Drupal 8]

Is there a better view for Drupal 8 than this one?

Comment: `In Drupal 8 there's no aggregation or sorting possible.` [Doesn't this thing sort?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZL5M.jpg)

Comment: those are just filters. no sorting / aggregation. I see a lot of selects from cache_* which could have been grouped nicely to make this data more useful to find actual pain points